# Solve for variable inside expected value

Tags: probability

I have the following equation that involves expectations

$c=\mathbb{E}[(a+\eta x)^{-\sigma}x]$, where $x$ is a random variable with support $(-\infty, \infty)$.

$a,c,\eta$ are constants.

I want to solve for $\eta$. Here is what I have done:

$c=\int_{-\infty}^\infty (a+\eta x)^{-\sigma}x f(x)dx$
Where $f(x)$ is the density function of $x$. I tried to solve the indefinite integral by parts:

$u=(a+\eta x)^{-\sigma}x \rightarrow du=(a+\eta x)^{-(\sigma+1)}(a-\eta(\sigma-1)x)dx$, and
$dv=f(x)dx \rightarrow v=F(x)$ where $F(x)$ is the cumulative probability function.

$\int (a+\eta x)^{-\sigma}x f(x)dx=(a+\eta x)^{-\sigma}x F(x)-\int F(x) (a+\eta x)^{-(\sigma+1)}(a-\eta(\sigma-1)x)dx $

I want to solve the last integral by parts but I have no idea what to choose as $u$ or $v$,

Thank you

Comment: Is $\sigma$ positive or negative and real or an integer?

Comment: $\sigma$ is a positive real

Comment: Do you know the PDF and/or CDF of $x$?

Comment: Are you wanting the PDF of $\eta$ or some other statistic about it?

Comment: $x$ is a random variable with pdf $f(x)$ and CDF $F(x)$, I want to  get $\eta$ out of the expectation and express it in terms of the other parameters. $\eta$ is a constant.